# $4+\sqrt{5}$ is a prime member of $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{5})$

Tags: ring-theory

definite ring $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{5})=\{a+\sqrt{5}b\,|\,a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$

show that $4+\sqrt{5}$ is a prime member of $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{5})$

Comment: note the norm of the number is $4^2 - 5 1^2 = 11$ which is a prime number, so it's probably a prime we can't rule it out yet..

Comment: Don't you mean $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{5}) = \{a+\sqrt{5}b\,\lvert\, a,b\in\mathbb{Z} \}$?

Comment: @Sh4pe: yes, this is

Comment: @Muniain: You could edit your question then... :)

Comment: This ring is normally called $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$. $\Bbb{Z}(\sqrt{5})$ is its field of fractions.

Answer (score 4):

OK, after giving a wrong solution this morning (I blame it on the lack of coffee...), here is another try:

The standard field norm on $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5}]$ is $N(a+b\sqrt{5}) = |a^2 - 5b^2|$. It is multiplicative, and $N(4+\sqrt{5}) = |4^2 - 5\cdot 1^2| = 11$ is prime, so $4+\sqrt{5}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$, and more generally in the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q} [\sqrt{5}]$, which is $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2\right]$.

Now irreducibility in general does not imply primality, but it does in [Euclidean domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain). (More general, this statement is true in [Unique Factorization Domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain), and every Euclidean domain is a UFD.) It is known that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5}]$ is norm-Euclidean, i.e., that the standard field norm $N$ is Euclidean on the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2\right]$. The standard reference for the discussion of the question for which integers $d$ the domain $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is Euclidean seems to be the book of [Hardy and Wright](http://books.google.com/books/about/An_Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Numbers.html?id=rey9wfSaJ9EC).

Now if $4+\sqrt{5}$ divides some $a+b\sqrt{5}$ in $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2\right]$, then $$  \begin{split} a+b\sqrt{5} &= (4+\sqrt{5})\left(c+d\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2\right) \\ & = 4c+2d+\frac{5}2d + \left( c+\frac{d}2+ 2d)\right)\sqrt{5}. \end{split} $$
Since the coefficients are integers $a$ and $b$, we get that $d$ is even, and so $c+ d \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2 \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$. This implies that $4+\sqrt{5}$ actually divides $a+b\sqrt{5}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$. Now if $4+\sqrt{5}$ divides a product $xy$ with $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$, then it divides $x$ or $y$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2]$, so by the above argument it divides $x$ or $y$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$, showing that it is a prime element of this ring.

Comment: What are you using $|x|$ to mean?

Comment: All you seem to be showing is that $4+\sqrt{5}$ is irreducible. How do you then conclude that it is prime?

Comment: Chris, $|x|$ just means the absolute value in $\mathbb{C}$, and you are right, I missed that irreducibility does not imply primality (unless we know that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is a unique factorization domain, which I don't.)

Comment: If $|x|$ is absolute value, then $N(4+\sqrt{5})=(4+\sqrt{5})^2=21+8\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Ah, I guess it is too early for me to post answers here...

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is not Euclidean, or even a UFD. Perhaps you're confusing it with the ring of integers of $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{5}]$, which is $\Bbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right]$?

Comment: True, this is what I get as an analyst wading into algebraic number theory... But anyway, this still implies that $4+\sqrt{5}$ is prime, since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is a subring of the ring of integers.

Comment: Why? $2$ is prime in the ring of integers, but not in this subring.

Comment: Chris, you are right, this needed another argument, but I think it works now.

Comment: I don't understand what did you do?. By definition, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is integer domain, member $a$ is prime if $a\notin \mathbb{Z}*$ and from condition $a|bc$ implies $a|b$ or $a|c$.

Comment: It doesn't matter if $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ or not, the condition is $a|bc$ implies $a|b$ or $a|c$. And I think this is exactly what I do in the last paragraph, after having shown that $4+\sqrt{5}$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2\right]$ first.

Comment: so, $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}]$ is Euclide domain?. Can you give me a material say about this problem?. Thankful

Comment: The reference is linked to in the answer above, it is the book of Hardy and Wright.

Comment: Can you give me page number in that book?